# jQuery first option selected on backbutton in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a select box, and when someone hits the back button, I'd like the first option to be selected again. It works fine in Chrome and such, but not IE 8. Here's my code:

```
<select id="select-city">
   <option selected="selected">Choose city</option>
   <option value="Acton-Vale">Acton Vale</option>
   <option value="Alma">Alma</option>
   <option value="Amos">Amos</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#select-city')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try `$('#select-city').attr('selectedIndex', 0);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your JavaScript in a document ready block

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Yes! that does it. I did notice that it would be selected to the first option, then change to the previously selected. Not sure why i didnt think to try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var select = $('#select-city>option');
select[1].selected = true;
```